# Javascript true/false function

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript, and I just discovered strange behavior that I can't understand:

```
var magicVar = Math.sin;
magicVar == true; // it returns false
magicVar === true; // it returns false
if (magicVar) console.log("???"); // it prints "???"
```

What is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: because `magicVar` is a reference to a function which is truthy

Comment: `magicVAr` is something else than `magicVar `.

Comment: @Barmar try : `Boolean(Math.sin)`

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the great answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons), it'll give you more insight on what's happening and material to read.

Comment: 'truthy' means you can do something like this: `!!Math.sin==true` --> true

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: I would expect that in "if (magicVar)" would be "if (false)". becasue when I evaluate it directly with "magicVar == true" it returns me "false". Although it acts like "if (magicVar == false)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var magicVar = Math.sin;
```

From here on `magicVar` is a reference to the `Math.sin` function, which is actually an `Object` (see [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) on MDN)

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

---

```
magicVar == true; // it returns false
```

This is `false`: from the [Equality comparison and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) on MDN if you compare an operand of type `Object` with an operand of type `Boolean` using the `==` operator you always get `false` (look at the **Loose equality using ==** table).

[EDIT] As Bergi pointed out in the comments you could actually in some cases have objects that loosely compared to a boolean value return true.

What is actually happening behind the scenes is that the comparison algorithm described in [ES6 §7.2.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) is applied.

> 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(x).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(y).
> 3. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then Return the result of performing strict Equality Comparison x === y.
> 4. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 5. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 6. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 7. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 9. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 10. If Type(x) is either String, Number, or Symbol and Type(y) is Object, then return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 11. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 12. Return false.

In your case what happens is:

```
magicVar == true
magicVar == Number(true) // Step 9. x == ToNumber(y).
magicVar == 1
toPrimitive(magicVar) == 1 // Step 11. ToPrimitive(x) == y.
magicVar.toString() == 1
"function sin() { [native code] }" == 1
Number("function sin() { [native code] }") == 1 // Step 7. ToNumber(x) == y.
NaN === 1 // Step 3. x === y.
false
```

But comparing for example to an object like:

```
{
     valueOf: function(){
         return 1;
     }
}
```

you would get:

```
true == {valueOf(){return 1;}} // it returns true
```

---

```
magicVar === true; // it returns false
```

This is trivially `false`, the types of the operands are different and the `===` operator checks for the operands to have same types and values.

---

```
if (magicVar) console.log("???"); // it prints "???"
```

As all the others answers have said `magicVar` here is in a `Boolean` context and gets coerced to `true`

Comment: Can you anyway explain me this particular choice of design during the development of Javascript language?

Comment: I have to think about it. Anyway generally speaking keep in mind that not all javascript design choices could be optimal. The language has been developed in a very short time and certainly has its flaws. I suggest you this read on the subject https://books.google.ie/books/about/JavaScript.html?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&source=kp_cover&hl=en

Comment: @rji89 when you are satisfied with one of the answers, please don't forget to accept one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: You are oversimplifying `magicVar == true;`. There are indeed objects that are equal to a boolean, just try out `true == {valueOf(){return 1;}}`. That table on MDN is (was) simply wrong.

Comment: @Bergi that is not an object, it's a code block. If you don't trust MDN look at the standard http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison, the relevant case is point 12. Is the standard wrong aswell?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: I used a method shorthand (ES6), you might need to try `{valueOf: function(){return 1;}}`. No, the standard is not wrong (I know it well), the table on MDN was (before I fixed it). The relevant points are [ES6 §7.2.12 steps 8 and 9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: @Bergi I think got your point, you are right. I'll edit my answer to be more precise.

Comment: @Bergi anyway I wouldn't say that the table is wrong, it covers the Number, String an Boolean cases. The Object case should be considered only when your Object is not a Number, String or Boolean. My citation was oversimplifying indeed.

Comment: @Bergi No, now I finally understand, the table is actually wrong, If an object is not typeof(Number), but behaves as a Number, the behaviour will not be consistent with that table.

Comment: @Bergi take a look at my edit, I hope I got your point. Sorry for the attitude on my first comment but I put quite some effort in writing the answer and I thought it was correct. Feel free to edit if you like.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :-) Unfortunately it's still not quite right, as step 9 *is* applied for `Math.sin` before it gets to 12. So `magicVar == true` => `magicVar == 1` => `Number(magicVar) == 1` => `Number(magicVar.toString()) == 1` => `Number("function sin() { [native code] }") == 1` => `NaN == 1` => `false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84194/discussion-between-andrea-casaccia-and-bergi).

Answer (score 2):

`magicVar` is true *as a value*. It is true in the sense that it's not empty, it's not null or undefined. So, any non-null value would be a true value. But is **this value** *equal* to true ? No. It is true as a boolean not true as a value.

To summarize:

```
magicVar == true || magicVar === true; // returns false
Boolean(magicVar); // returns true
```

Comment: The question is *why* is it not equal to true when compared with the `==` operator?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia: Well, I said that it's value (as an `Object`, as you said) is ofcourse not equal to a value of type `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

The concept to grasp here is the difference between truthy and falsy values compared to true and false booleans. See [here for truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [here for falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Long story short, an `if` condition passes if the expression is truthy, and `magicVar` is a `function` (truthy).

Answer (score 0):

magicVar is not equal to true.
It is equal to the Math.sin function.

So, in the if statement, it is evaluated to a truthy value (it is defined and does not evaluate to a falsy value).

http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 0):

Comparison `function Math.sin` with `boolean` constant return `false`, because this variables have different types.
But when you put not-bool variable to `if` condition: for example `if (Math.sin)...` or `if (window)...` this return true if variable not equal null.

Comment: I understand that `magicVar === true` is false because it checks the type, but the `==` operator should perform type juggling, can you explain why `magicVar == true` is false?